# make app without of multitasking support

Tags: iphone, ios4

my application should not support multitasking , is there any to force app without multitasking support ?

Answer (score 3):

Set the [UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) key in your Info.plist file.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `applicationWillTerminate` in your `applicationDidEnterBackground` method of your application's delegate. Then the home button will have the same effect as it did on iOS versions prior to 4.0, without multitasking.