# How to stop running iphone app in background in iphone sdk 4.0 and above

Tags: iphone

Please tell me some solution for how to stop app at background when we close the app in iphone sdk 4.0 and above.

can any one provide me some sample code for it.

Thanks,
Priyanka

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437619/make-app-without-of-multitasking-support/4437913#4437913)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 app doesn't terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154491/iphone-4-app-doesnt-terminate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key in your app's Info.plist to `YES`.

This will make the app quit when you press the home button, instead of being backgrounded.